# SQL Server 2008 Pivot table aggregate function issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have this query and I am trying to group by surveyname but im getting this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'pvt.Follow Up' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
   surveyname, [Follow Up] AS Follow_Up, [Ambiance] AS Ambiance, 
   [Consultation] AS Consultation, [Procedure/Service] AS Procedure_Service
FROM 
   (SELECT
       s.name surveyname, q.question, subq.answer subquestion,aw.answerweight, 
       aw.score, rc.categoryname, sc.cweight
    FROM survey.dbo.results r
    JOIN survey.dbo.questions q ON r.questionidfk = q.id
    LEFT JOIN survey.dbo.answers subq ON r.itemidfk = subq.id
    LEFT JOIN survey.dbo.answers a ON r.answeridfk = a.id
    JOIN survey.dbo.surveys s ON q.surveyidfk = s.id
    join sigweb.dbo.survey_types_main stm on s.id = stm.surveyidfk
    join survey.dbo.survey_results sr on r.owneridfk = sr.ownerid
    join sigweb.dbo.BosleySurvey bs on bs.contactid = sr.contactid and stm.clientsurveytypeid = bs.surveytype
    join sigweb.dbo.contact c on sr.contactid = c.contactid
    join sigweb.dbo.patient p on p.contactid = c.contactid
    join sigweb.dbo.doctor d on p.doctorid = d.doctorid
    join sigweb.dbo.survey_tracking st on st.contactid = c.contactID and st.surveytypeid = stm.surveytypeid
    left join survey.dbo.answerweighting aw on isnull(r.itemidfk, r.questionidfk) = aw.questionitemidfk and r.answeridfk = aw.answeridfk
    left join survey.dbo.rating_categories rc on aw.categoryidfk = rc.id
    left join survey.dbo.survey_categories sc on aw.categoryidfk = sc.categoryidfk and s.id = sc.surveyidfk
    where 
       aw.answerWeight is not null) ps
PIVOT
(
   AVG(score)
   FOR categoryname IN
    ( [Follow Up], [Ambiance], [Consultation], [Procedure/Service])
) AS pvt
```

group by surveyname

This is an example of the results im getting

```
SURVEYNAME      FOLLOW_UP   Ambiance   Consultation   Procedure_Service
Review             NULL     NULL    NULL          9.81
Review             9.54     NULL    NULL          NULL
Consultation       5        NULL    NULL          NULL
Consultation       NULL     5           NULL          NULL
Consultation       NULL     5           NULL          NULL
Consultation       NULL     5           NULL          NULL
Consultation       NULL     5           NULL          NULL
Consultation       NULL     5           NULL          NULL
Consultation       NULL     NULL    5         NULL
Consultation       5        NULL    NULL          NULL
Consultation       NULL     NULL    5         NULL
```

This is an example of the data before the pivot:

```
Review          6   Follow Up
Review          9   Procedure/Service
Consultation    5   Ambiance
Consultation    5   Ambiance
Consultation    5   Ambiance
Consultation    5   Ambiance
Consultation    5   Ambiance
Consultation    5   Ambiance
Consultation    5   Consultation
Consultation    5   Consultation
```

The idea is to group by the `surveyname` and have only two results in the end.

Comment: I added the result before the pivot

Comment: try removing the fields from the inner select that you are not including in your final `SELECT` these - `q.question, subq.answer subquestion, aw.answerweight, sc.cweight`. These fields are probably making the rows distinct so the `GROUP BY` is not working.

Comment: Add this as an answer so I can accept it please. I removed the extra columns from the subquery and it worked fine even without the `group by` function

Comment: added an answer, glad you got it figured out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are including too many columns in the inner `SELECT`, try to remove the columns:

```
q.question, subq.answer subquestion, aw.answerweight, sc.cweight
```

They are most likely making the rows `DISTINCT` so the `GROUP BY` does not work properly. So your query will be:

```
SELECT surveyname, 
    [Follow Up] AS Follow_Up, 
    [Ambiance] AS Ambiance, 
    [Consultation] AS Consultation, 
    [Procedure/Service] AS Procedure_Service
FROM 
(
    SELECT s.name surveyname, 
        aw.score, 
        rc.categoryname, 
    FROM survey.dbo.results r
    JOIN survey.dbo.questions q 
        ON r.questionidfk = q.id
    LEFT JOIN survey.dbo.answers subq 
        ON r.itemidfk = subq.id
    LEFT JOIN survey.dbo.answers a 
        ON r.answeridfk = a.id
    JOIN survey.dbo.surveys s 
        ON q.surveyidfk = s.id
    join sigweb.dbo.survey_types_main stm 
        on s.id = stm.surveyidfk
    join survey.dbo.survey_results sr 
        on r.owneridfk = sr.ownerid
    join sigweb.dbo.BosleySurvey bs 
        on bs.contactid = sr.contactid 
            and stm.clientsurveytypeid = bs.surveytype
    join sigweb.dbo.contact c 
        on sr.contactid = c.contactid
    join sigweb.dbo.patient p 
        on p.contactid = c.contactid
    join sigweb.dbo.doctor d on p.doctorid = d.doctorid
    join sigweb.dbo.survey_tracking st 
        on st.contactid = c.contactID 
            and st.surveytypeid = stm.surveytypeid
    left join survey.dbo.answerweighting aw 
        on isnull(r.itemidfk, r.questionidfk) = aw.questionitemidfk 
            and r.answeridfk = aw.answeridfk
    left join survey.dbo.rating_categories rc 
        on aw.categoryidfk = rc.id
    left join survey.dbo.survey_categories sc 
        on aw.categoryidfk = sc.categoryidfk and s.id = sc.surveyidfk
    where aw.answerWeight is not null
) ps
PIVOT
(
   AVG(score)
   FOR categoryname IN
    ( [Follow Up], [Ambiance], [Consultation], [Procedure/Service])
) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where the error is coming from in what you have posted (I assume it is when you try and add `GROUP BY SurveyName` to the end of the query you have posted), but you need to remove the redundant columns from your subquery, so you only select the 3 columns you need, `surveyname`, `score`, and `categoryname`:

```
SELECT 
   surveyname, [Follow Up] AS Follow_Up, [Ambiance] AS Ambiance, 
   [Consultation] AS Consultation, [Procedure/Service] AS Procedure_Service
FROM 
   (SELECT
       s.name surveyname, aw.score, rc.categoryname
    FROM survey.dbo.results r
    JOIN survey.dbo.questions q ON r.questionidfk = q.id
    LEFT JOIN survey.dbo.answers subq ON r.itemidfk = subq.id
    LEFT JOIN survey.dbo.answers a ON r.answeridfk = a.id
    JOIN survey.dbo.surveys s ON q.surveyidfk = s.id
    join sigweb.dbo.survey_types_main stm on s.id = stm.surveyidfk
    join survey.dbo.survey_results sr on r.owneridfk = sr.ownerid
    join sigweb.dbo.BosleySurvey bs on bs.contactid = sr.contactid and stm.clientsurveytypeid = bs.surveytype
    join sigweb.dbo.contact c on sr.contactid = c.contactid
    join sigweb.dbo.patient p on p.contactid = c.contactid
    join sigweb.dbo.doctor d on p.doctorid = d.doctorid
    join sigweb.dbo.survey_tracking st on st.contactid = c.contactID and st.surveytypeid = stm.surveytypeid
    left join survey.dbo.answerweighting aw on isnull(r.itemidfk, r.questionidfk) = aw.questionitemidfk and r.answeridfk = aw.answeridfk
    left join survey.dbo.rating_categories rc on aw.categoryidfk = rc.id
    left join survey.dbo.survey_categories sc on aw.categoryidfk = sc.categoryidfk and s.id = sc.surveyidfk
    where 
       aw.answerWeight is not null) ps
PIVOT
(
   AVG(score)
   FOR categoryname IN
    ( [Follow Up], [Ambiance], [Consultation], [Procedure/Service])
) AS pvt
```

In the background you are also grouping your end results by `q.question, subq.answer subquestion,aw.answerweight, sc.cweight` because they are included in the subquery, but because the are not in the select list you are not seeing immediately the effect this is having.

Comment: i removed q.question, subq.answer subquestion,aw.answerweight, sc.cweight and my query works